# How do I write a waf file for a custom compiler?

Tags: build, build-automation, waf, calibre

I got sick of looking up the magic symbols in make and decided to try [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/).

I'm trying to use calibre to make ebooks and I'd like to create a wscript that takes in a file, runs a program with some arguments that include that file, and produces an output. Waf should only build if the input file is newer than the output.

In make, I'd write a makefile like this:

```
%.epub: %.recipe
    ebook-convert $ .epub --test -vv --debug-pipeline debug
```

Where % is a magic symbol for the basename of the file and $ a  symbol for the output filename (basename.epub).

I could call `make soverflow.epub` and it would run ebook-convert on soverflow.recipe. If the .recipe hadn't changed since the last build, it wouldn't do anything.

How can I do something similar in waf?

(Why waf? Because it uses a real language that I already know. If this is really easy to use in scons, that's a good answer too.)

Comment: I gave up on waf and found that it's pretty easy to do in [scons](http://www.scons.org/). The documentation has a section on [Writing Your Own Builders](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-writing). See [more details here](https://hastebin.com/ohezulesoz.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to make a basic wscript file, but I don't know how to build targets specified on the command-line.

---

The Waf Book has a section on [Task generators](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html#_task_generators). The [Name and extension-based file processing](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html#_name_and_extension_based_file_processing) section gives an example for lua that I adapted:

```
from waflib import TaskGen
TaskGen.declare_chain(
        rule         = 'ebook-convert ${SRC} .epub --test -vv --debug-pipeline debug', 
        ext_in       = '.recipe', 
        ext_out      = '.epub'
)

top = '.'
out = 'build'

def configure(conf):
        pass

def build(bld):
    bld(source='soverflow.recipe')
```

It even automatically provides a clean step that removes the epub.