# How do I create a new compiler profile with Waf?

Tags: waf

I've found this very helpful [page](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/apidocs_16/tools/compiler_c.html) in the API docs of the Waf build system:

My wscript looks like this:

```
def options(opt):
        opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):
        from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler
        c_compiler['linux'] = ['mycc']
        conf.load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):
        bld.program(source='main.c', target='nop')
```

I've tried creating the file **mycc.py**, placing it in waflib/extras and recompiling Waf. However, when I try to configure my project using this new profile, I get the following error:

```
Setting top to                           : /home/user/waf/example 
Setting out to                           : /home/user/waf/example/build 
Checking for 'mycc' (c compiler)         : not found 
could not configure a c compiler!
(complete log in /home/user/waf/example/build/config.log)
```

I've also tried creating waflib/extras/mycc.py in the root of my project (the place where Waf is and from where it gets called). No good.

How do I do this?

Comment: How does your mycc.py look like? I think you are also missing loading it. If I remember correctly waf will try to load those modules named with c_* automatically when loading compiler_c, so maybe this might already help.

Comment: This may help also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445848/how-do-i-write-a-waf-file-for-a-custom-compiler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613253/using-a-non-standard-c-compiler-with-waf