# Using a non standard c compiler with Waf

Tags: build, waf

I have a non standard c compiler, for the example lets call it comp.

How can I use it with Waf?

I see that in all the examples:

```
def options(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')
```

And I want to load my own compiler - comp, so that any build or task will be assosiated with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to define your own c_compiler tool, see for example [icc in waflib/Tools](https://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/waflib/Tools/icc.py) or [c_bgxlc in waflib/extras](https://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/waflib/extras/c_bgxlc.py), modules called c_* in extras will be automatically loaded by load('compiler_c').